# GAE appcfg.py deploy always upload all files (instead changed only)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

I've started to have a problem today.

Everytime I run `appcfg.py update .` it updates 441 project files.
Even if I just modified 1 it will upload 442.

running `appcfg.py update .` twice will upload 441 files every time.

This is obviusly a problem because instead uploading a couple of files it is uploading a lot of them and taking a lot of time.

This is what I have tried:

- Updated app engine launcher to it latest version
- Rebooted
- removed all files from the folder, download them again from git

nothing seems to work.

I even left only app.yaml and index.php and it uploaded both files every time, even if I do not change anything.

Ideas?  thanks

Comment: btw, tried another module, different project, and it uploads all files too.

Comment: same problem here. Was fine until today and now its uploading every single static file - uploads take forever. Other modules are instant. I'm about to set up another module and treat it as a CDN at this stage

Comment: Glad I am not crazy!!  so it is something GAE side.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. Uploading the files are always fast for me.

Comment: No, till yesterday, if I modify 1 file, it would upload that file only.
Expected behaviour is to upload changed files only

Comment: @DiegoSucaria: Hm, I didn't deploy for several months now, so things *might* have changed in the meantime, but in all my deployments so far **all** the files were uploaded - indicating marcadian's response would be correct. What's your expectation based on, do you have a pointer to some documentation indicating updates should be incremental only ?

Comment: @DanCornilescu I am basing on my own experience, I've been working on GAE during the last 6 months, and every time I deployed only the changed files were uploaded.  This problem started yesterday

Answer (score 0):

**it is fixed now.**

At the moment of this answer, *google seems to have fixed the issue*.

Just tried to deploy and it only uploaded the modified files.

Comment: omg....yes it is soo much better. It was killing me it took over 10 minutes per deploy. Testing was a nightmare.

Comment: I was in the same scenario!